# Install git2go libgit2 dependency on windows through vcpkg

Tags: go, libgit2, vcpkg

In order to use git2go I install libgit2 through vcpkg `vcpkg.exe install libgit2:x64-windows --recurse` and it installs successfully.
Unfortunately, vcpkg does not provide the openssl.pc for pkg-config, hence git2go fails when running any code stating

```
# pkg-config --cflags  -- libgit2
Package openssl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `openssl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'openssl', required by 'libgit2', not found
pkg-config: exit status 1
```

If I cannot install libgit2 through vcpkg, how can I make it work with git2go? Is there a way to tell vcpkg to provide the openssl.pc? Running `vcpkg.exe install openssl:x64-windows` states that the package is already installed. Running `vcpkg.exe integrate install` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

1. add a `vcpkg_fixup_pkgconfig()` call to the `portfile.cmake` of libgit2
2. add a `openssl.pc` file to the openssl port in vcpkg. Open up an issue if you like. Unfortunately the openssl sources seem to not have a template (`openssl.pc.in`) for that so it probably needs manual creation. (Maybe you are lucky and the linux build creates one which could be used and adapted to windows.)